# глючит chromedriver

Tags: python, chromedriver

не пойму в чем может быть проблема, через терминал запрашиваю:

```
root@sky:~# chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 115.0.5790.98 (4eacc220b55f07c57d5a1f4b7e0e63a6f7e420a1-refs/branch-heads/5790_90@{#4})
root@skymec:~# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 115.0.5790.98
```

Но через раз скрипт выдает ошибку, что у меня не соответствие версий, что это за плавающий баг?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/parser.py", line 39, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 443, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 54, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 674, in start_session
    super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:45215
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.96
```

Comment: Почему строки приглашения в терминале разные?

Comment: И почему вы вообще работаете от рута?

Comment: ошибка разработчика, issue уже есть